# Is it possible to use django-crispy-form FormHelper without modifying Form class

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-authentication, django-crispy-forms

For the sake of consistency I want to use crispy with my login form.
I'm using `'django.contrib.auth.views.login'` and I'm only coding the template.

The problem is `{% crispy form %}` doesn’t output submit button nor "next" hidden field.

Is there any way to create `FormHelper` outside of `forms.py` ( it's in contrib.auth so I would need to try to extend `AuthenticationForm` or something like it) an then use it in the template without modifying `views.py`(also in contrib.auth)

If it would require any ninjitsu with extending classes etc. I will go with pure HTML but if there is a simple way to include 'external' `FormHelper` on the template level i would regret not asking

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why do you need to use `{% crispy form %}` and not just the `crispy` filter. I'm using crispy in my login form, overriding the template from django.contrib.auth, this way:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block body %}

<form method="post" action="" class="form-signin">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans "Log in" %}</button>
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: One may not want to simply crispy the entire form -- for example, since I handle my errors separately, I do not want them displayed in the form.